# Why am I getting FormatException on this?

Tags: c#, string, double, formatexception

I am trying to convert a *System.string* to a *System.double*, the input is:  `He: 4.002602 amu`

Code:

```
string[] data = line.Replace(" ", "").Replace("amu", "").Split(new char[] { ':' }); 
double i = Convert.ToDouble(data[1]);
```

I have tried:

```
string[] data = line.Replace(" ", "").Replace("amu", "").Split(new char[] { ':' }); 
double i = Convert.ToDouble(data[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It might helpful to try and get rid of so many nested calls. Split up the `Replace()` calls until you get to the exact location of the error. Fix it, then you can slap them all into that one statement again if you want (though it won't run any faster that way).

Comment: Works for me. Something has to be different?

Comment: Your second attempt works for me with the input you provided - what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Same as the first one,@DStanley ,heres proof: https://gyazo.com/c46579cfa80525b53db2f900b1b7a6e1 (picture sharing site).

Comment: I dont usually have these bad habits, @Frecklefoot, its just that I am getting insane with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Convert.ToDouble()` use the `double.Parse()` method, preferably using the invariant culture when the user input is always using a period sign as decimal separator.

So try something like this:

```
double i = double.Parse(data[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

EDIT:

I've seen in the screenshot you posted in the comments above that you're not actually checking the contents of `data[1]` before passing it to the `Convert.ToDouble` method.

According to MSDN the only case when a `FormatException` is thrown should be when providing a non-numeric text value ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1)). Therefor I'd suggest to add a check for empty strings and `null` values before, passing the value to the `Convert.ToDouble()` method. Try updating your code to something like this:

```
foreach (string line in raw) {
    string[] data = line.Replace(" ", "").Replace("amu", "").Split(new char[] { ':' }); 
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data[1]) {
        double i = Convert.ToDouble(data[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    } else {
        // Invalid value in data[1]
        // Maybe set a breakpoint here and investigate further if necessary
    }
}
```

If this still throws a `FormatException` then the contents of `data[1]` must be some non-numeric and non-empty text value, so in that case you should probably check the contents of the `data` array using the debugger and find out how / why that invalid value got there.

Comment: Under the hood, [`Convert.ToDouble(string)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,d98fcd7819f63d0f) just calls `double.Parse()`.

Comment: Tried that too, no luck.

Comment: @Guilherme Almeida Then have you looked at the contents of data[1]? It must be some non-numeric but non-empty text then.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, I have debugged it through MessageBoxes with a literal at the end just so I made sure there is no empty space at the end. I swapped the "." to a ",". Cant get it working :[

Comment: But what are the contents of data[1] now exactly in this case? Could you maybe copy-paste the value or post another screenshot showing the contents of the data array during such an error? (EDIT: when the exception pops up, just expand the "data" array in the Locals window of Visual Studio and copy-paste / screenshot these values)

Answer (score 0):

If format of input is *something+blank*+**doubleNumber**+*blank+something* you can use following code:

```
string line = "He: 4.002602 amu";

int intLspacePos = line.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
int intRspacePos = line.LastIndexOf(" ");

string strNumber = line.Substring(intLspacePos, intRspacePos - intLspacePos);
double dblNumber = Convert.ToDouble(strNumber);
```

Comment: No, it does not. It would if my input was your "line" variable, you missed the ":".

Comment: @Guilherme Almeida! 
The code was updated to fetch double number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regular expression without splitting a string which mixed with number and words:

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions

var resultString = Regex.Match(line, @"\d.\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert with specific culture info as below. 2057 is LCID for English (UK).

double i = Convert.ToDouble(data[1], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(2057));